# Get NIST time timeout using C# in Unity for iOS

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the time from the NIST servers. We have set up a timeout but it doesn't work. We want to request the time of each server and if it doesn't get any or all the info within that timeout then jump to the next one.

Our code is:

```
private static DateTime GetNISTDate() { 
        int timeout = 300;
        var result = DateTime.MinValue;     
        // Initialize the list of NIST time servers
        // http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi
        string[] serversArray = new string[] {
            "nist1-pa.ustiming.org",
            "time-a.nist.gov",
            "time-b.nist.gov",
            "time-c.nist.gov",
            "time-d.nist.gov",
            "nist1.aol-va.symmetricom.com",
            "nist1.columbiacountyga.gov",
            "nist1-chi.ustiming.org",
            "nist.expertsmi.com",
            "nist.netservicesgroup.com",
            "wwv.nist.gov",
            "time.nist.gov"
        };
        List <string> servers = new List<string> (serversArray);
        // Try 5 servers in random order to spread the load
        while (servers.Count > 0)
        {
            int index = UnityEngine.Random.Range (0, servers.Count);
            string server = servers [index];
            servers.RemoveAt (index);
            try
            {
                // Connect to the server (at port 13) and get the response
                string serverResponse = string.Empty;
                System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tcpClient;
                tcpClient = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();

                var resultOfConnection = tcpClient.BeginConnect(server, 13, null, null);
                int millisecondsEnter = DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond;
                var success = resultOfConnection.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout));
                int millisecondsExit = DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond;

                tcpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;

                if (success) {
                    tcpClient.GetStream().ReadTimeout = timeout;
                    serverResponse = (new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream())).ReadToEnd();
                    tcpClient.Close();
                } else {
                    tcpClient.Close();
                    throw new Exception("Failed to connect.");
                }

                // If a response was received
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverResponse))
                {
                    // Split the response string ("55596 11-02-14 13:54:11 00 0 0 478.1 UTC(NIST) *")
                    string[] tokens = serverResponse.Split(' ');

                    // Check the number of tokens
                    if (tokens.Length >= 6)
                    {
                        // Check the health status
                        string health = tokens[5];
                        if (health == "0")
                        {
                            // Get date and time parts from the server response
                            string[] dateParts = tokens[1].Split('-');
                            string[] timeParts = tokens[2].Split(':');

                            // Create a DateTime instance
                            DateTime utcDateTime = new DateTime(
                                Convert.ToInt32(dateParts[0]) + 2000,
                                Convert.ToInt32(dateParts[1]), Convert.ToInt32(dateParts[2]),
                                Convert.ToInt32(timeParts[0]), Convert.ToInt32(timeParts[1]),
                                Convert.ToInt32(timeParts[2]));

                            // Convert received (UTC) DateTime value to the local timezone
                            result = utcDateTime;

                            return result;
                            // Response successfully received; exit the loop

                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            catch
            {
                // Ignore exception and try the next server
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Seems to be working just great. Which part is causing issues?

Comment: It tries to connect and if it begins to get the package but it gets it slow then the timeout doesn't appear. It could take up to 40 seconds to exit of the method. What i would like to do is if the packet is not fully received within the timeout then continue to the next web.